# Summation of two Gaussian distributed data with different coefficient of mean and variance

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, mean, sum

I need some help on Gaussian distribution. i have two dataset, both are identical and independent distributed, but having mean as 2μ_1 and μ_2, same scenario for the variance. How can I add them?

thank you.

Comment: Hey Tonni, welcome to CrossValidated. Your question is unclear. You need to "add distributions"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: hi Gijs, Thank you for your response.  I need to add variable  X with Y where X and Y are independent and identically distributed with having mean 2μ_1 and μ_2 respectively. In addition, they have variance 2σ_1 and σ_2. How can I add them?

Answer (score 0):

Create two distributions each with NOB values via monte carlo using the respective mean/variance and simply add them pairwise to create a NOB realizations for the sum. Then compute statistics for the summed set.

Comment: Thank you, Can you please kindly give an example?